# Merge sorted Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

preciso realizar um merge em java, com valores de uma Instância de uma classe, Fila a e Fila b, fiz um método inserir(), na classe Fila. e gostaria de acessar os valores de a e b. E atribuir esses valores, a uma outra Instância da classe Fila, tipo Fila c = new Fila(recebe os valores de A e B). Mais não tenho muito ideia de fazer isso, agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda.

Classe Fila, com outros métodos

```
public class Fila {

    private int remove;
    private int max = 0;
    public int dado[];

    public Fila(int tamanhoFila) {
        this.dado = new int[tamanhoFila];
        this.remove = 0;
    }

    Fila() {
        this(3);
    }

    public  void insere(int elemento) {
        if (this.max < this.dado.length) {
            this.dado[this.max] = elemento;
            this.max++;
        }
    }

    public void cheia() {
        if (this.max == this.dado.length) {
            System.out.println("A Fila esta cheia");
        } else {
            System.out.println("A Fila não esta cheia");
        }
    }

    public boolean vazia() {
        if (this.max == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Object primeiro() {
        if (this.vazia()) {
            return "A fila esta vazia !";
        }

        return this.dado[0];
    }

    public Object ultimo() {
        return this.dado[--max];
    }

    public Object remove() {
        int pos = 0;
        int removeElemento = this.dado[pos];

        for (int i = pos; i < this.max - 1; i++) {
            dado[i] = dado[i + 1];
        }
        this.max--;

        return removeElemento;

    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(this.dado);
    }

}
```

Classe Executa, com o método main

```
public class Executa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fila a = new Fila(4);
        Fila b = new Fila(5);
        Fila c = new Fila(9);

        a.insere(12);
        a.insere(35);
        a.insere(52);
        a.insere(64);


        b.insere(05);
        b.insere(15);
        b.insere(23);
        b.insere(55);
        b.insere(75);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione esse construtor com esses dois parâmetros a mais, `fila1` e `fila2`,
fila1 será a fila que terá o seu primeiro valor (do `dado`) no começo do `dado` da fila sendo instanciada:

```java
Fila(int tamanhoFila, Fila fila1, Fila fila2) {
    this.dado = new int[tamanhoFila];
    this.remove = 0;

    int i = 0, j = 0; // Guarda a posição atual em fila1.dado e fila2.dado
    // Repete até não sobrar valores a ler nos dois
    while (i != fila1.dado.length || j != fila2.dado.length) {
        // O valor de fila1.dado[i] é o primeiro a ser adicionado
        if (i < fila1.dado.length) {
            this.dado[i+j] = fila1.dado[i];
            i++;
        }
        // O valor de fila2.dado[j] é adicionado depois
        if (j < fila2.dado.length) {
            this.dado[i+j] = fila2.dado[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Com esses parâmetros, o seu exemplo necessita que a `Fila c` seja instanciada dessa forma:

```java
Fila c = new Fila(9, b, a);
```

Comment: Fiz o método construtor, como informado acima. Só que na hora de instanciar na classe Executa, ele me apresenta erros na instância. Apresentando erros no b e a.
public class Executa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Fila c = new Fila(9, b, a);

    }

}

Comment: Veja se você instanciou `c` somente após inserir os valores das outras duas `Filas`, se ainda estiver com o problema edite sua pergunta mostrando o que tentou e onde e quais são os erros.

Comment: Consegui resolver, muito Obrigado.

Comment: Se você conseguiu de outro jeito, responda a sua pergunta com a sua solução e a marque como correta, para ajudar outras pessoas com alguma dúvida parecida.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei um método para tal solução

public static Fila merge(Fila filaA, Fila filaB) {
        Fila filaC = new Fila(filaA.dado.length + filaB.dado.length);

```
    int proximoA = 0;
    int proximoB = 0;
    int proximoC = 0;

    while (proximoA < filaA.dado.length && proximoB < filaB.dado.length) {
        if (filaA.dado[proximoA] <= filaB.dado[proximoB]) {
            filaC.dado[proximoC++] = filaA.dado[proximoA++];
        } else {
            filaC.dado[proximoC++] = filaB.dado[proximoB++];
        }
    }

    while (proximoA < filaA.dado.length) {
        filaC.dado[proximoC++] = filaA.dado[proximoA++];
    }

    while (proximoB < filaB.dado.length) {
        filaC.dado[proximoC++] = filaB.dado[proximoB++];
    }

    return filaC;

}
```

e no método main, o código ficou assim

public class Executa {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Fila filaA = new Fila(4);
    Fila filaB = new Fila(5);

    filaA.insere(2);
    filaA.insere(4);
    filaA.insere(5);
    filaA.insere(6);

    filaB.insere(9);
    filaB.insere(1);
    filaB.insere(10);
    filaB.insere(3);
    filaB.insere(12);

    Fila filaMergeada = Fila.merge(filaA, filaB);

    filaMergeada.mostrarElementosDaFila();

}
```

}